# How to schedule a work when user connects or disconnect to WiFi using WorkManager?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have some tasks to run when the user connects (and disconnects) to WiFi. Before android O, I was using implicit intents in the manifest. But now due to the new restrictions I can't use them anymore. 
I tried to use the new component `WorkManager` to schedule a task to happen when the user connects to Wifi, however I don't understand how to set this specific constraint. The `Constraints.Builder()` has only one method related to network and it's `setRequiredNetworkType()`.

Can you suggest how can I set this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

you can define constraints like this

```
 Constraints myConstraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                    // Many other constraints are available, see the
                    // Constraints.Builder reference
                    .build();

            PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder job =
                    new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyJob.class, 15,
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES).setConstraints(myConstraints);

            // Create the actual work object:
            PeriodicWorkRequest periodicJob = job.build();
            // Then enqueue the recurring task:
            WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(mergeInspectionsRequest);
```

**EDIT**

To run job only once use  OneTimeWorkRequest

```
  OneTimeWorkRequest onetimeJob = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyJob.class)
                    .setConstraints(myConstraints).build();
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(onetimeJob);
```

Comment: But doesn't NetworkType.CONNECTED, means that it can also been regular mobile connection?

Comment: it means the job will only be executed if any internet connection is available

Comment: u can use NetworkType.NOT_REQUIRED if you want to execute a job that doesn't require internet connection , you can use NetworkType.UNMETERED for wifi only

Comment: I see, but can I make the job happen only when there is change in network status. What I mean is, I don't want to check every 15 minutes (or any amount of time) for connectivity, but start the job only when the user connected or disconnected from WiFi. Just like it happens when using implicit broadcast receivers.

Comment: check edit ,if you want to run job only once use OneTimeWorkRequest

Comment: you want to run the jobs always whenever the connection changes ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I want to run the jobs only when the connection changes.

Comment: in this case you need to run your service as a foreground service and listen for connection changes your self . in this case you will have to show notification for the user at least for api >26

Comment: I see, I can't use foreground service, because the part that I'm writing is small part of a bigger library.
Do you know maybe if I can get raw information about connections from proc/net from the system?

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions ,you can  use broadcast-receiver and added to manifest to check for connection changes .it will work for android 9

Comment: @has19 None of these broadcast receivers will serve that purpose or maybe you know a specific one?

Comment: @Keselme I am also stuck in the same exact situation. Did you find any solution? especially through workmanager.

Comment: @Keselme your right ,the only way it is possible is to check for network changes in the app ,at least for android 24 and above

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION

Comment: @wahib, what I did eventually is to create a job service. I use onStart() to initialize a broadcast receicer to listen to wifi connections. In onStop() i just reschedule the jobservice again.

Comment: @has19 yes I am aware of it but the problem with CONNECTIVITY_ACTION is that it is deprecated in API level 28 and can only be used with context registered receivers which means it won't run beyond app being killed.

Comment: @WahibUlHaq yes, u can use this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#registerNetworkCallback(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent) if you only needed in the app

Comment: @Keselme ok! This is not really any different approach to using PeriodicWorkRequest and just make it repeat automatically at a certain time. I would actually recommend it over JobService and handling scheduling yourself. But I got your point. This is also what I ended up using. Not perfect but I don't find any better solution than this one which makes it continuously listen to wifi change events and even beyond app being killed.